# Copy files containing one of the word from list

Tags: java, bash, grep

I have large code base in front of me. In this I want to find the files(path) that contain the class definition and copy the file to a folder. I have a list of class names(about 50) to look for.

I've tried using `grep` like

`cp $(grep  --include=\*.java -rl . -e "class SplashScreen" *) --parents -t ./dest-folder`

It works, but it takes a lot of time to find even one class through code.
I could write a script looping though every class name will take a long time and i don't want to do it manually for every class.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The GNU guys managed to make a real mess of `grep` by giving it options to find files. POSIX `grep` is simple, any version of `find` is simple - meanwhile GNU `grep` with built-in `find`-like functionality is Frankenstein's monster lumbering through the villages... Please [edit] your question to state what `grep  --include=\*.java -rl . -e "class SplashScreen" *) --parents -t ./dest-folder` is supposed to do and add some concise, testable sample input and output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list of class names in a file `list.txt` (one class name per line):

```
MyClass1
MyClass2
MyInterface1
```

it is possible to process this file to build up a regexp to select the class names and store it into a variable:

```
$ class_names="$(cat list.txt|tr '\n' '#'|sed 's/#/\\|/g')"
```

Then you can run your script using `grep` or you could use `find`.

```
$ cp $(find ./src -type f -name "*.java" -exec grep -l "\(class\|interface\) \($class_names\)" {} +) --parents -t ./mydest-dir
```

Or, without the temporary variable the final command may look like this:

```
$ cp $(find ./src -type f -name "*.java" -exec grep -l "\(class\|interface\) \($(cat list.txt|tr '\n' '#'|sed 's/#/\\|/g')\)" {} +) --parents -t ./mydest-dir
```

To make sure the required files are copied successfully, use the same `find`:

```
$ find ./mydest-dir -type f -name "*.java"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-f` to define a file of patterns to apply. You can include regex metacharacters in the patterns.
You can use `shopt -s globstar` to access filenames at indeterminate depth.

If `pats` is the name of your pattern file,

```
shopt -s globstar
cp --parents -t ./dest-folder $( grep -l -f pats **/*.java )
```

Comment: This will complain if there are no matches, but shouldn't be problem using a pattern file.